How to parse the word document containing project structure to arrays of file paths
How to convert the project structure provided in a word document to the array of valid file paths in java.
Ex:
Input:
test-app/
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   ├── com.company.test/
│   │   │   │   ├── controller/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── TestController.java
│   │   │   │   ├── model/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── Test.java
│   │   │   │   ├── repository/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── TestRepository.java
│   │   │   │   ├── service/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── TestService.java
│   │   │   ├── Application.java
│   │   ├── resources/
│   │   │   ├── application.properties
│   ├── test/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   ├── com.company.Test/
│   │   │   │   ├── controller/
│   │   │   │   ├── service/
│   │   │   │   ├── repository/
├── pom.xml

Output:
String[] output = ["test-app/src/main/java/com/company/test/controller/TestController.java", "test-app/src/main/java/com/company/test/service/TestService.java", "test-app/src/main/java/com/company/test/model/Test.java", "test-app/src/main/java/com/company/test/repository/TestRepository.java",..............]

java snippet to parse the word doc and get the structure as an array of strings.

Better to ask about your actual goal. You do realise that com.company.Test is not an real directory but three directories?

Your input looks like plain text.  Is that plain text what the Word document contains?  Does your program need to read that Word document, or can you paste that text into a regular .txt file and have your program read from that?

Yes, I will store it in a txt file and the program should return me the expected output as mentioned in question. @VGR

This example uses Files.lines stream and regular expression to break your input into the file components as String[]. It does not address the directory name flaw pointed out by g00se and is easy to adjust to deal with use of other line separators.
public static String[] parse(Path txt) throws IOException {
    final ArrayList<String> components = new ArrayList<>();
    try (var lines = Files.lines(txt)) {
        return lines.map(String::trim).filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty))
            .mapMulti((line, c) -> {
                int depth = line.replaceAll("[^│├]", "").length();
                while(components.size() > depth)
                    components.remove(components.size()-1);
                components.add(line.replaceAll("(.*├── )?", ""));
                if (!line.endsWith("/"))
                    c.accept(String.join("", components.toArray(String[]::new)));
            }).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}

Ideally you'd use Path.of or Paths.get at the end for path components. The mapMulti step identifies the depth of each component and saves the filename part in components.
